# Generate random number specific number of times in R

Tags: r

I want to create an random index of {1,2}, where {1} would come **exactly** 23 times, and {2} would come **exactly** 24 times.

I tried using the `prob` argument in the `sample` function in R like this:

`sample(x = c(1,2),size = 47, replace = TRUE,prob = c(23/(23+24),24/(23+24)))`

But I am not getting {1} an exact number of 23 times and {2} an exact number of 24 times, which is what I want. I know that taking repeatedly large number of trials would give me an average of 23 times for {1}, and 24 times for {2} using the `prob` argument, but I want the number of repetitions for {1} and {2} to be exactly 23 and 24 times each time.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: `sample(c(rep(1,23), rep(2,24)))`

Comment: @r2evans, I feel like this must be a dupe ... if not, you should post as answer.

Comment: Using `prob=`, it is improbable that you will get your 23 (and therefore 24) count often (or even *much*). It's random, by definition it will vary. The only way to control it is to control the count *before* shuffling things around (randomly).

Comment: @BenBolker I agree, as I've made similar comments in the past ... but I can't find it (and I won't spend hours looking).

Comment: so go ahead and answer, and we can close later if/when we or someone else finds it.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah, I agree that the `prob` argument doesnt give exact number of time. Your solution in the first comment worked like a charm. Can you let me know what `rep` is doing and which argument is it (as in, is `rep` the `size` argument for `sample` function?)

Comment: Oh actually, now that I looked closely, I got what you did @r2evans. Thanks